# Realloc crash my programa

Tags: c, realloc

Where problem ??, i trying do it with much forms but with realloc giveme errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define numbs 10
//math.h para pow();
int main(){
    int *array = malloc(numbs * sizeof(int));
    if (array == NULL){
        printf("Error in memory 1");
        return -1;
    }
    int numbschanger = NULL;
    int guardarcounter = NULL;
    int *changedirinmemory = NULL;
    int counter = NULL; // 0
    int saveint = NULL;
    int integer;
    int numero = NULL;
    int res = pow(2,3); // 2 ** 3 = 8, Una potencia.
    printf("%d\n",res);
    scanf("%d",&numero); // Guardar en la direccion numero.
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Los divisores de %d son:\n",numero);
    for(integer = 1;integer <= numero;integer++){
        if (numero % integer == 0){ // Integer 1 porque si hacemos una divicion de numero / 0 Nos dara o un aviso en la consola de que no se puede dividir entre zero o un crash en el .exe
            array[counter] = integer;
            printf("%d\n",array[counter]);
            counter++;
        }   
        if (counter > numbs){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Haven\'t problem 01\n");
    guardarcounter = counter;
    saveint = integer; //Guardada el numero del integer, para que en el nuevo espacio de memoria pueda seguir comprobando "if (numero % integer == 0)"
    for(integer;integer <= numero;integer++){
        if (numero % integer == 0){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (numbs < counter){
        printf("Campo del crash.");
        numbschanger = numbs + counter;
        changedirinmemory = realloc(array,numbschanger * sizeof(int)); //Crash hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
        if (changedirinmemory == NULL){
            printf("Error in memory 2");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    printf("Haven\'t problem 02\n");
    for(saveint;saveint <= numero;saveint++){
        if (numero % saveint == 0){
            changedirinmemory[guardarcounter] = saveint;
            printf("%d\n",changedirinmemory[guardarcounter]);
            guardarcounter++;
        }
    }
    printf("Haven\'t problem 03\n");
    if (changedirinmemory != NULL){
        free(changedirinmemory);
        printf("\n\nEl nuevo espacio de memoria esta libre.");
    }
    else{
        free(array);
        printf("\n\nArray Libre.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` is UB on most platforms.

Comment: I have problem in line 45 "changedirinmemory = realloc(array,numbschanger * sizeof(int));"

Comment: Great - what does your debugger tell you about the state of the relevant variables (`array`, `numbschanger`, etc) at that point ? And what is the value of `numero` ?

Comment: 0 Warnings and 0 Errors

Comment: The damage probably happened before you reached `realloc`. `if (counter > numbs){ break; }` What about when they are equal? You'll be writing beyond `array` bounds.

Comment: If you compiler could state the code is correct for any code, it solved the _halting problem_. Plase state which compiler it is, I have to get this!

Comment: -> -> Detenido -> -> pre-Símbolo (BGF) -> -> Símbolo    Compiler = DEV C++

Comment: Weather Vane The error is detected in the realloc, i put printfs for test where crash

Comment: @MR.NothingImportant I get warnings. Two warnings, to be exact. In lines 37 and 52 "warning: statement with no effect". So what did you forget to switch on?

Comment: Also "no warnings"? I advise you to enable the warnings, since the `NULL` values you assign to `int` should generate warnings. "'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'"

Comment: @MR.NothingImportant I read what you put, but if you don't want to listen, then don't. You caused *undefined behaviour* a few lines above.

Comment: DEV C++ 5.9.2 Don't giveme warnings :/

Comment: I can't understand where fail, in lines 37 and 52, i don't detect nothing strange.

Comment: @MR.NothingImportant do you know what the statement `saveint;` does?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/bHyfcpwW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Weather Vane does not want to…

You problem lies in line 31 `if (counter > numbs)`. That is not enough if `counter` is equal to `numbs`

With input `6125346` -> crash
Change line 31 to `if (counter >= numbs)`
Again with input `6125346` -> works perfectly

But you have a lot of small things in your code that are not fully correct. Please see the comments you got. You can also go to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for further enlightenment but your code needs to *work* in the first place, otherwise they'll tear you into fine shreds.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ouch! %§§&%$ C&P! Thanks!

Comment: // Stored integer number , so that in the New Memory space can continue checking " if ( saveint == 0 % ) "

Comment: Thanks for help deamentiaemundi :D

Comment: Noob error, is because the array[10] can't go to value 11, array[9] = MAX, sorry for lost your time, if (counter > numbs - 1)